# TreeView set Foreground and font

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I Have a control I made using Winforms some years ago, I'm trying to rewrite it using WPF.
I'm using a Treeview (unbound) Control as my base control, I need to change the foregroug color and font-size of some items depending on values I gather. 
I tried setting the foregroud using code :

```
    TreeViewItem n = new TreeViewItem();
    n.Header = item.Name;
    n.Tag = item;
    n.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
```

No luck.
any help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what did you do with that item? If i create such an item and add it to a TreeView it does have a `LightGreen` text.

If you want to apply some coloring conditionally you might want to create a [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) with [`Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Trigger.aspx) which is applied to all `TreeViewItems` (set it as [`TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) for example or add it to the TreeView.Resources with only a `TargetType` and not `x:Key`).

Comment: I found that the problem is with Devexpress controls. Hosting a treeview (or other control) in a styled windows, the new control's style  is overrided by the window's style. I'm waiting for a solution from their support.